# Different flex behaviour: Chrome vs Firefox, child problem when image has % height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I've just observed a strange behavior on a somewhat contrived flex example: Firefox and Safari show one thing while Chrome behaves differently (probably the difference is in the flex algorithm). I'd like to fire a bug, but I don't know which result should be expected - I understand why Firefox and Chrome behave like that but I simply ignore the intended way.

Here is the code (please note that the flex item - that is, the .col - doesn't have any explicit height and we are in the default `align-items:stretch` setting):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

you can find a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Nescioke/pen/dyKNVez)

This is how this page looks on Firefox/Safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnYvS.png

and this is how it shows on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDYFi.png

What do you think? Which flex algorithm works as intended? Who is right?

Answer (score 0):

I created demo

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" height=100% >
  </div>
</div>
```